# Playing AVAudio from iPod Library while device is locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

Just a quick question.

I've set up my program to be able to play `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVPlayer` in the background, which is working fine. I can play a song, lock my screen and the sound will continue to play.

What I'm having trouble with is calling `[AVPlayer play]` whilst my screen is ALREADY locked. This ultimately results in no music being played.

Comment: I know that the answer has already been selected so your problem is solved, but I cannot understand how your program is even running while the screen is already locked.

Comment: @DevinGund This is done by specifying "Required background modes" in your .plist file to tell iOS that the application should be allowed to play audio even when it isn't in the foreground.

Comment: @MDT Yes so when you close the application the audio will continue to run, but when the device is locked your application is not running.  So how can it tell iOS to play a song if the device is already locked?

Comment: @DevinGund I think I see what you're saying, I'm sure iOS is just listening for whichever application has most recently called for a playback session and triggers this applications control events automatically.

Comment: @DevinGund I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say. What I meant was that i'd leave my application running, then when it has automatically locked, or the user has pressed the lock button, I would like my sound to play at a pre-specified time. I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell your player to listen for control events:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Then you can act on them like so:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) 
        {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay) 
            {
            [AVPlayer play];
            } 

        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) 
            {
            [AVPlayer pause];
            } 
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause) 
            {
                if (!AVPlayer.playing) 
                    {
                        [AVPlayer play];

                    } else if (AVPlayer.playing) 
                    {
                        [AVPlayer pause];
                    }
            }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack)
            {
            [self myNextTrackMethod];
            }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack)
            {
            [self myLastTrackMethod];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect and the reply time is incredible! How can I select yours as the accepted answer?

Comment: @DejanLukić Looks like you already figured it out! Glad to help! I've made an edit to my answer, this should make it fit your needs better.

Comment: Flawless! More than what I needed, in fact.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DejanLukić No problem, and if you are looking into adding next/last track functionality, this can easily be done by creating an array of the track names and telling your next/last methods to play the objectAtIndex of the array and adding or subtracting from it to navigate between songs.

Comment: Thanks, that'll come in handy for the future, as all the examples i've seen on this have been a lot more difficult than what you've just described, but for the time being i'm only needing one sound to use as an alarm.

The best thing about your answers/comments is the lack of over-complicated blocks, thanks heaps!

Comment: @DejanLukić The first time I had to think about implementing this it seemed pretty overwhelming, but once you do it once you realize it isn't so bad. When you do need to add next/last functionality feel free to comment on this post again. I'll get the notification and will probably be able to help you out!