# Full-featured music player using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, audio-player

I'm writing a music player for iOS that needs to have all the features of the built-in Music app. My app needs to continue running in the background so I have to use the AVPlayer class.

Are there any open source implementations out there that I can use instead of writing the whole thing myself?

Comment: Are you basically asking whether you can copy a music player app and re-release it under your name? I'm afraid no.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, I'm not trying to copy any app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this. It works great:

https://github.com/gangverk/GVMusicPlayerController

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play tracks from your iTunes music library, and don't want to use the `MPMusicPlayerController` class, your best bet is to use `AVPlayer` or `AVQueuePlayer` (subclass of `AVPlayer`). You must establish the appropriate audio session and register to receive remote control events for the app to continue playing music in the background.

There are downsides to this method; you won't be able to play DRM-protected tracks and audiobooks purchased from the iTunes store. There's no way to instantiate an iTunes Match download with the `AVPlayer` class. Furthermore, you'll have a bit of work on your hands if you want to add gapless playback and equaliser settings (The closest you'll get to gapless playback is with the `AVQueuePlayer` subclass, though in theory, you could overlap `AVPlayer`s with an `NSTimer`).

You'll also need to change 'Required Background Modes' in your Info.plist to 'App plays audio'

As for the rest of your app, I suggest you read up on `UITabBarController`s and `UITableViewController`s along with `MPMediaQuery`s.

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515950/1064869) for the audio part.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to get bits and pieces together to make it work. I am looking for a ready-to-use solution like a library or something.

Comment: I'm not so sure, you stated `AVAudioPlayer` before you changed it `AVPlayer` just now, and you want 'all the features of  the built-in Music app' which isn't possible. That's why I explained the above. It's a bit of work to make an app like this and I doubt anyone would make it readily available after putting in all that effort. Good luck though!

Comment: AVAudioPlayer was just a copy/paste error, sorry about that. As I said, I'm just checking for availability of an existing solution before I start to write the whole thing myself.